# Duplicate Rows when using Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have table employeeLogs show like this:

```
Emp_ID    Datetime                    State
0001      2015-03-19 10:44:40.000     LogIN
0002      2015-03-19 10:44:44.000     LogIN
0001      2015-03-19 10:44:49.000     LogOUT
1003      2015-03-19 10:44:54.000     LogIN
0002      2015-03-19 10:45:03.000     LogOUT
1003      2015-03-19 10:45:08.000     LogOUT
0001      2015-03-19 10:45:11.000     LogIN
0001      2015-03-19 15:12:30.000     LogOUT
```

I want rows LogIN and LogOut to make Column and execute their respective datetime and I query like this :

```
select distinct et.Emp_ID, f.LogIN, t.LogOUT from Emp_TimeLogs et

inner join

(

SELECT  distinct Emp_ID, [LogIN] , [LogOUT]
FROM 
    ( SELECT Emp_ID, 
             State,
             Date_Time  , 
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Emp_ID DESC) ) AS RowNum         
      FROM Emp_TimeLogs et
   ) p 
PIVOT ( max(Date_Time)   
      FOR [state] IN ([LogIN],[LogOUT]) 
       ) AS pvt 
  WHERE DATENAME(Weekday,[LogIN]) <> 'Saturday'
) f on  
et.Emp_ID = f.Emp_ID
inner join 
(
SELECT  distinct Emp_ID, [LogIN] , [LogOUT]
       FROM 
    ( SELECT 
           Emp_ID, 
           State,
           Date_Time  , 
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Emp_ID DESC) ) AS RowNum 
       FROM Emp_TimeLogs et     
    ) p 
    PIVOT ( max( Date_Time )
        FOR [state] IN ([LogIN],[LogOUT]) 
          ) AS pvt 
    WHERE DATENAME(Weekday,[LogOUT]) <> 'Saturday'
  ) t on  
et.Emp_ID = t.Emp_ID
```

But the result is this :

```
Emp_ID _____________LogIN________                   LogOUT

0001___    2015-03-19 10:44:40.000_____  2015-03-19 10:44:49.000  
0001___    2015-03-19 10:44:40.000_____  2015-03-19 15:12:30.000
0001___    2015-03-19 10:45:11.000_____  2015-03-19 10:44:49.000
0001___    2015-03-19 10:45:11.000_____  2015-03-19 15:12:30.000
0002___    2015-03-19 10:44:44.000_____  2015-03-19 10:45:03.000
1003___    2015-03-19 10:44:54.000_____  2015-03-19 10:45:08.000
```

the `Emp_ID` are repeated or duplicate.

I would like to have result like this :

```
Emp_ID _____________LogIN________                   LogOUT

0001___    2015-03-19 10:44:40.000_____  2015-03-19 10:44:49.000
0001___    2015-03-19 10:45:11.000_____  2015-03-19 15:12:30.000
0002___    2015-03-19 10:44:44.000_____  2015-03-19 10:45:03.000
1003___    2015-03-19 10:44:54.000_____  2015-03-19 10:45:08.000
```

Is there any solution? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos :sql-sever 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a much simpler way to get what you want:

```
SELECT Emp_ID, [LogIN], [LogOUT]
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID, State ORDER BY Date_Time) AS rn,
          Emp_ID, Date_Time, State 
   FROM Emp_TimeLogs) p
PIVOT
(
   MAX (Date_Time)
   FOR State IN ( [LogIN], [LogOUT] )
) AS pvt
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1ea9/1)

To explain this, the source query for `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID, State ORDER BY Date_Time) AS rn, 
       Emp_ID, Date_Time, State 
FROM Emp_TimeLogs
ORDER BY Emp_ID, Date_Time
```

generates the following result set:

```
rn  Emp_ID  Date_Time               State
--------------------------------------------
1   0001    2015-03-19 10:44:40.000 LogIN
1   0001    2015-03-19 10:44:49.000 LogOUT
2   0001    2015-03-19 10:45:11.000 LogIN
2   0001    2015-03-19 15:12:30.000 LogOUT
1   0002    2015-03-19 10:44:44.000 LogIN
1   0002    2015-03-19 10:45:03.000 LogOUT
1   1003    2015-03-19 10:44:54.000 LogIN
1   1003    2015-03-19 10:45:08.000 LogOUT
```

The cross-tab is generated by rotating (`LogIN`, `LogOUT`) pairs for each (`rn`, `Emp_ID`) pair.